# Sort An array with its specified key value PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array like

```
Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 3870
        [title] => Ignacio GonzÃ¡lez visita los terrenos donde se ubicarÃ¡ el futuro aerÃ³dromo del Suroeste
        [id_galeria] => 3784
        [noticia_id] => 
        [medio] => 
        [programa] => 
        [fecha] => 2013-06-26
        [created] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
        [video] => /descargas/flv/20130626_aerodromo.flv
        [descargable] => /descargas/mp4/20130626_aerodromo.mp4
        [miniatura] => /images/img/videos/20130626_01.jpg
        [published] => 1
        [checked_out] => 0
        [checked_out_time] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
        [noticia] => 6020
        [metakey] => 
        [ordering] => 
        [state] => 1
        [created_by] => 
    )
[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 3871
        [title] => Ignacio GonzÃ¡lez inaugura la Sede del Instituto MadrileÃ±o de Estudios Avanzados de EnergÃ­a, puntero a nivel mundial
        [id_galeria] => 3785
        [noticia_id] => 
        [medio] => 
        [programa] => 
        [fecha] => 2013-06-26
        [created] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
        [video] => /descargas/flv/20130626_indea.flv
        [descargable] => /descargas/mp4/20130626_indea.mp4
        [miniatura] => /images/img/videos/20130626_02.jpg
        [published] => 1
        [checked_out] => 0
        [checked_out_time] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
        [noticia] => 6021
        [metakey] => 
        [ordering] => 
        [state] => 1
        [created_by] => 
    )

[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 3879
        [title] => Ignacio GonzÃ¡lez visita los terrenos donde se ubicarÃ¡ el futuro aerÃ³dromo del Suroeste
        [id_galeria] => 3784
        [noticia_id] => 
        [medio] => Telemadrid
        [programa] => 
        [fecha] => 2013-06-26
        [created] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
        [video] => /descargas/flv/20130626_aerodromo_presidencia.flv
        [descargable] => /descargas/mp4/20130626_aerodromo_presidencia.mp4
        [miniatura] => /images/img/videos/20130626_01_tm.jpg
        [published] => 1
        [checked_out] => 0
        [checked_out_time] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
        [noticia] => 6020
        [metakey] => 
        [ordering] => 
        [state] => 1
        [created_by] => 
    )

[3] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 3867
        [title] => Ignacio GonzÃ¡lez recibe al Real Madrid de Baloncesto tras proclamarse CampeÃ³n de Liga
        [id_galeria] => 3778
        [noticia_id] => 
        [medio] => 
        [programa] => 
        [fecha] => 2013-06-25
        [created] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
        [video] => /descargas/flv/20130620_baloncestorealmadrid.flv
        [descargable] => /descargas/mp4/20130620_baloncestorealmadrid.mp4
        [miniatura] => /images/img/videos/20130620_01_tm.jpg
        [published] => 1
        [checked_out] => 0
        [checked_out_time] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
        [noticia] => 6010
        [metakey] => 
        [ordering] => 
        [state] => 1
        [created_by] => 
    )

[4] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 3868
        [title] => Ignacio GonzÃ¡lez inaugura el nuevo Centro de Salud de Rivas-Vaciamadrid
        [id_galeria] => 3782
        [noticia_id] => 
        [medio] => 
        [programa] => 
        [fecha] => 2013-06-25
        [created] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
        [video] => /descargas/flv/20130625_salud.flv
        [descargable] => /descargas/mp4/20130625_salud.mp4
        [miniatura] => /images/img/videos/20130625_01.jpg
        [published] => 1
        [checked_out] => 0
        [checked_out_time] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
        [noticia] => 6018
        [metakey] => 
        [ordering] => 
        [state] => 1
        [created_by] => 
    )

[5] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 3869
        [title] => Ignacio GonzÃ¡lez entrega los Premios de la Revista Mercados del Vino y la DistribuciÃ³n
        [id_galeria] => 3783
        [noticia_id] => 
        [medio] => 
        [programa] => 
        [fecha] => 2013-06-25
        [created] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
        [video] => /descargas/flv/20130625_vino.flv
        [descargable] => /descargas/mp4/20130625_vino.mp4
        [miniatura] => /images/img/videos/20130625_02.jpg
        [published] => 1
        [checked_out] => 0
        [checked_out_time] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
        [noticia] => 6019
        [metakey] => 
        [ordering] => 
        [state] => 1
        [created_by] => 
    )

[6] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 3872
        [title] => Ignacio GonzÃ¡lez inaugura el nuevo Centro de Salud de Rivas-Vaciamadrid
        [id_galeria] => 3782
        [noticia_id] => 
        [medio] => Telemadrid
        [programa] => 
        [fecha] => 2013-06-25
        [created] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
        [video] => /descargas/flv/20130625_telemadrid_rivascentrosalud.flv
        [descargable] => /descargas/mp4/20130625_telemadrid_rivascentrosalud.mp4
        [miniatura] => /images/img/videos/20130625_01_tm.jpg
        [published] => 1
        [checked_out] => 0
        [checked_out_time] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
        [noticia] => 6018
        [metakey] => 
        [ordering] => 
        [state] => 1
        [created_by] => 
    )

[7] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 3864
        [title] => Ignacio GonzÃ¡lez visita una residencia donde conocerÃ¡ una aplicaciÃ³n para confeccionar menÃºs equilibrados para mayores
        [id_galeria] => 3780
        [noticia_id] => 
        [medio] => 
        [programa] => 
        [fecha] => 2013-06-24
        [created] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
        [video] => /descargas/flv/20130624menu.flv
        [descargable] => /descargas/mp4/20130624menu.mp4
        [miniatura] => /images/img/videos/20130624_01.jpg
        [published] => 1
        [checked_out] => 0
        [checked_out_time] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
        [noticia] => 6016
        [metakey] => 
        [ordering] => 
        [state] => 1
        [created_by] => 
    )

[8] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 3865
        [title] => Ignacio GonzÃ¡lez asiste a la entrega de la II EdiciÃ³n de los Premios a la Excelencia Educativa del Ayuntamiento de las Rozas
        [id_galeria] => 3781
        [noticia_id] => 
        [medio] => 
        [programa] => 
        [fecha] => 2013-06-24
        [created] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
        [video] => /descargas/flv/20130624_excelencia.flv
        [descargable] => /descargas/mp4/20130624_excelencia.mp4
        [miniatura] => /images/img/videos/20130624_02.jpg
        [published] => 1
        [checked_out] => 0
        [checked_out_time] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
        [noticia] => 6017
        [metakey] => 
        [ordering] => 
        [state] => 1
        [created_by] => 
    )

[9] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 3873
        [title] => Ignacio GonzÃ¡lez visita una residencia donde conocerÃ¡ una aplicaciÃ³n para confeccionar menÃºs equilibrados para mayores
        [id_galeria] => 3780
        [noticia_id] => 
        [medio] => Telemadrid
        [programa] => 
        [fecha] => 2013-06-24
        [created] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
        [video] => /descargas/flv/20130624_telemadrid_menusmayores.flv
        [descargable] => /descargas/mp4/20130624_telemadrid_menusmayores.mp4
        [miniatura] => /images/img/videos/20130624_01_tm.jpg
        [published] => 1
        [checked_out] => 0
        [checked_out_time] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
        [noticia] => 6016
        [metakey] => 
        [ordering] => 
        [state] => 1
        [created_by] => 
    )
)
```

And I want to sort an array with its key value called `[noticia]`. I have tried a lot but I failed to sort with this key value without changing its indexing.

I need sort an array with two key value at the same time means with fecha (date) most recent and also sort array with noticia. How can I do this?

Comment: Currently i am using this function to sort array but i never get result that i want i don't what i am using wrong.function sorttitle($a, $b)
{
  if ($a->noticia == $b->noticia) return 0;
  return ($a->noticia < $b->noticia) ? 1 : -1;
}
uasort($this->items, 'sorttitle');

Comment: Here is the orginal array [link]http://doceysumando.ddns.net:18080/icm-indra2/index.php/videos/videos/0?start=500
i want to sort array with DESC order

Comment: the [noticia] values which is empty here?

Comment: name of the parent array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sorts the array by noticia field in DESC order using [uasort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php) function:

```
function fn($a, $b) {
     if ($a['fetcha'] == $b['fetcha']) {
        if($a['noticia'] == $b['noticia']) {
           return 0;
        }
        return ($a['noticia'] > $b['noticia']) ? -1 : 1;
    }
    return ($a['fetcha'] > $b['fetcha']) ? -1 : 1;
}
uasort($arrayName, "fn");

echo "<pre>";print_r($arrayName);
```

Comment: i need sort an array with two key value at the same time means with fecha(date) most recent and also sort array with noticia.
How can i do this?

Comment: you are welcome Prabhash :)

Answer (score 0):

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
  return strcmp($a->count, $b->count);
}
usort($your_array, "cmp");
```

Use [usort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)

Comment: what are $a and $b ?! how is the cmp function fed with $a and $b ?

Comment: @AfghanWiz,  please read documentation as link provided in the answer.

Comment: if i want to sort with noticia and sort also with fecha means most recent first ..

then what i do?

Comment: i need simple array with most recent first and also sort by noticia.
did you understand my need its little bit confusing i know but please help me out

Comment: @ProgrammingStudent, Yes you are right! :)

Comment: Don't know why 2 downvotes for a correct answer.